# Почему не приходят письма в postfix из вне?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, roundcube

Из postfix наружу все ок. А обратно ну никак. postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = server1.ru-central1.internal
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Порты открыты : 25,110,465,587,993,995
Письма шлю из yandex. Недоставленное сообщение : `Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.1.1 Unknown user; ZsLKhtpkoO5g-2Mu9GyOl; user not found`

Из wordpress ,из формы обратной связи все ок,письма приходят.

```
sudo traceroute mail.mydomain.ru -T -p 110 -n
traceroute to mail.mydomain.ru (158.*****), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 * * *
2 158**** 0.572 ms 0.628 ms 0.682 ms
sudo traceroute mail.mydomain.ru -T -p 25 -n
traceroute to mail.mydomain.ru (158.******), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 * * *
2 158.****8 0.211 ms 0.202 ms 0.194 ms

~$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 110
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
~$ sudo netstat -tulpn |grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12464/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      12464/master
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      12537/dovecot
```

Answer (score 0):

mx запись указывает на другой сервер. проверьте днс. локально доходит потому что отправляется локально.